# Laravel: How to access variable from one model to another

Tags: laravel, variables, model

I have two models which correspond to two respective tables in my database: `ParticipantLookupModel` and `EventParticipantModel`. Everytime I add a record inside my `event_participant_tbl`, the record should be added in `participant_lookup_tbl` first, then the former. So you can look at it as a parent-child-relationship.

This is how my `participant_lookup_tbl` (in a nutshell) looks like:

```
p_id | fName | lName | companyName
```

And this is how my `event_participant_tbl` (in a nutshell) looks like:

```
p_id | p_id_fk
```

You can already tell that my `p_id_fk` is a foreign key that references `p_id` from `participant_lookup_tbl`. So everytime I call a function that inserts a record inside my `participant_lookup_tbl`, its last inserted `p_id` has to be inserted as a value in my `p_id_fk` from `event_participant_tbl` as well.

In my `ParticipantLookupController`:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
  $this->validate($request, [
        'fName' => 'required|string|max:191',
        'lName' => 'required|string|max:191',
        'compName' => 'required|string|max:191'
    ]);

    $participant = ParticipantLookupModel::create($request->all());
    $id = $participant->participant_id;
    return ['message' => $id]; //test if it returns the correct id
}
```

I have successfully returned the correct last inserted `p_id`. But I don't know how to access it inside my `EventParticipantController`.

In my `EventParticipantController`:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    //access $id from ParticipantLookupController and save
}
```

I know that this might be just a very simple problem. But any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Just a small note: In the title, I meant, "How to access variable from one Controller to another"..

Comment: as far i understood you have to create `event_participant_tbl ` model when created `participant_lookup_tbl`. so, take a look on model observers. i suppose `creating` event fits

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to go to another controller for this? You can do it in the same method of **ParticipantLookupController**

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'fName' => 'required|string|max:191',
        'lName' => 'required|string|max:191',
        'compName' => 'required|string|max:191'
    ]);

    $participant = ParticipantLookupModel::create($request->all());
    return redirect()->action(
       'EventParticipantController@store', ['id' => $participant->id]
    );
}
```

In this updated section you need to use the **id** as the parameter of your **store** method of **EventParticipantController**

```
public function store($id) {
    //check $id exists and save or abort
}
```

Comment: Sadly, yes.. I am calling the `store` function via Vue function. And I have to handle them separately, since I am also doing checking for existing records on both tables before I insert to them.

Comment: Check the updated answer. Does it fulfill your need?

Comment: No. Besides, the parameter for function `store` is intended for making a post request.